# How to run ipython notebook with batch file on Windows 10?

Tags: batch-file, jupyter-notebook, windows-10, ipython

I tried to write this code into `start notebook.bat` file, but it doesn't work. I'm trying to run it in a directory like `H:\python-workspace\KI\`

```
rem -- start_ipython_notebook_here.bat ---
dir
ipython notebook
pause
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Batch file works now very well ;-)

```
@echo off 
title My Jupiter Notebook Starter
set _anaconda_root=D:\Programs\Anaconda
color 1a

echo  Hallo Toni!
echo '-----------'
echo Press 1 to start notebook in H: workspace
echo or
echo Press 9 to start notebook in C: workspace

set /p _ws=

if %_ws% == 1 goto w1
if %_ws% == 9 goto w2

:w1
cls
set working_dir=H:\python-workspace
echo You work now into %working_dir%
call %_anaconda_root%\Scripts\activate.bat %_anaconda_root%
ipython notebook %working_dir%
pause
exit

:w2
cls
set working_dir=C:\Users\Toni Zeidler\PytonProjects
echo You work now into %working_dir%
call %_anaconda_root%\Scripts\activate.bat %_anaconda_root%
ipython notebook %working_dir%
pause
exit
```